# PAPR (Peak to average power ratio) of OFDM signals

Tags: digital-communications

Will the PAPR of an OFDM signal using QPSK modulation on its subcarriers be different than the PAPR of an OFDM signal using QAM256 on its subcarriers? assuming the same number of subcarriers

Comment: QPSK has fixed carrier amplitude,  variable phase. When you sum a bunch of those, what comes out? Versus the variable amplitude and phase of QAM256, for each carrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the PAPR of an OFDM signal using QPSK modulation on its subcarriers be different than the PAPR of an OFDM signal using QAM256 on its subcarriers?

No, not in general, which an easy sum notification using the QAM and PSK symbols in amplitude&phase notation would have yielded.

Of course, you still have the central limit theorem, but that's exactly that: a theorem about what happens in the limit, and you haven't defined the number of subcarriers.